# Working wiith DAO and singleton, problems with code

Tags: java, mysql, database, singleton, dao

maybe anybody could help me out. i'm working with Data access object. 
i have a database:
table Receiverz

```
num   name
 1    Walmart
 2    Target
 3    McDonalds
```

i've created a class for this table

```
public class Receiverz {
private int num;
private String name;

public void setNum(int num) {
    this.num = num;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

then i created Dao interface and passed a method to it:

```
public interface Dao {

Receiverz getReceiverz(int num);}
```

Then i created a class ExpensesDao that implements Dao and created a singleton in it(i aslo set up the connection with database but i will skip that part) and overrode getReceivers(int num) method by making it possible to work with database:

```
public class ExpensesDao implements Dao {

private static Dao thisdao;
public static synchronized Dao getDao() {
    if (thisdao==null) {
        thisdao = new ExpensesDao();
    }
    return thisdao;
    }

@Override
public Receiverz getReceiverz(int num) {
    Receiverz receiver = new Receiverz();
    try {
        Statement stmt = myConnection.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM receiverz");
        while(result.next()){

            receiver.setNum(num);
            receiver.setName(result.getString(2));

            }

    }
        catch (SQLException e){
             System.out.println(e.getMessage());
         }
    return receiver;

}
```

when i try to run it in main class:

```
public class TryDatabase {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Dao ex = ExpensesDao.getDao(); 
    System.out.println(ex.getReceiverz(2));
```

all i get is:

```
listexpenses.Receiverz@193499fd
```

but i have to get

```
2 Target
```

(since i passed 2 in the parameters and it refers to Target in my database.
does anyone know what's going wrong and what i should change in my code. P.S. i hope i made it clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ex.getReceiverz(2)` is returning a `Receiverz` object. Thus the `System.out.println(ex.getReceiverz(2));` is using the `toString()` method inherited from `java.lang.Object`. Create a `toString()` method in the `Receiverz` class that will output it the way you want.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, what you really need to do is change your SQL query. `"SELECT * FROM receiverz"` is going to retrieve all the records from the table so the while loop is going to go through every record, and the last one in the table is what gets set. Just change the query to `"SELECT * FROM receiverz WHERE num = ?"` and then use a [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) to execute the query. Then there will just be one result that is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

add a getName to your recieverz and change to this ex.getReceiverz(2).getName()

Answer (score 0):

A bit offtopic, but I recommend the [double checked locking singleton](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dcl/index.html) code to avoid all concurrency issues in initalization.

Ps.: ex.getReceiverz(2).getName() breaks [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter), might be better to avoid it.